# pnpm get stuck at Ready

Tags: reactjs, pnpm

just installed pnpm and after pnpm dev in my dev folder it gets stuck at ready in x.xs :

*PS C:\Users\username\offtime> pnpm dev*

*> offtime@0.1.0 dev C:\Users\s.bourhim\offtime*

*> next dev*

- ▲ Next.js 14.0.3*

*- Local:        http://localhost:3000*

*(node:12228) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time*

*(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

*✓ Ready in 4.3s*

Do anyone have any idea how to solve this? running Windows 11 latest update. Thanks in advance.